# How to get the author / owner of an article in MediaWiki 1.6?

Tags: php, mediawiki

I need to find the author name of an article in MediaWiki 1.6 programmatically.

I am using the title class of MediaWiki, but I don't think it contains a function to get the owner name of the article.

Comment: can i ask why am i down voted?

Comment: Use proper grammar, punctuation and complete sentences.  Also, show us what research you've done on this.  Tell the community what you've done so far, and what the results were.  Post code if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT rev_user_text 
FROM revision 
WHERE rev_page = {the page id}.
```

You can get the Page ID from the Title object.

Answer (score 0):

Articles in MediaWiki don't have owners. I don't think there is a function to return the usernames of everyone who has edited an article. You can always query the database directly.

Comment: can you give me the sql? mediaWiki db structure is quite confusing i tried to make sql but couldn't thats why i posted here